# Using Controller Variable in DB Query Builder in a Model - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

At the moment i have Query inside my Controller method made using Query Builder. Like so:

```
 public function postFilters(){
    $filt = Input::get('name');
    $query = DB::table('wm.top_pages')->where('filter',$filt)->limit(20)->get();

    return View::make('topPages.table', ['wm'=>$query]);
}
```

I would like to get the query outside of Controller and into my Model. But everytime i do this, i get an error because the same query as above, but now inside my model does not recognize the variable $filt, which actually gotten from my View. Can anyone advise on how to go about this? 
What i have done above is actually not what MVC should look like and i'm assuming there are ways of getting around it. I just cant make sense of most of the documentation on this specific topic.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Passing it as an argument springs to mind here... That's what they're for after all

Comment: Thank you. Was right in front of my nose the entire time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Elias Van Ootegem:

I passed on the variable as a parameter/argument to the model function and it worked.
Controller:

```
 public function postFilters(){
   $filt = Input::get('name');
   $query = webmasters::getFilters($filt);
   return View::make('topPages.table', ['webmasters'=>$query]);
 }
```

Model:

```
class webmasters {
   public static function web($filt) {
   $top_pages = DB::table('wm.top_pages')->where('filter',$filt)->limit(20)->get();
   return $top_pages;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well if I were you, I would create a Repository interface, and create an implementation to it, in this implementation I would add all my queries, and then the variable filter would be passed as an argument, then in my controller I would inject my interface (which is really simple using laravel).
So I end up with an application which is extensible, if I ever want to switch from MySQL to another database all I have to do is to create a new implementation and configure laravel to use the new implementation. That's how I do it. if you want to learn more about the Repository pattern, [here's a good article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600097/Why-the-Repository-Pattern)

Comment: Thank you. Even though this is better practice. I chose to go the easier way of passing the variable on to the model function as a parameter. It is afterall my initial laravel project and i'm getting used to the nuts and bolts of it.

Comment: You made the good decision starting with Laravel, you'll learn a powerfull framework and a lot fo good practices as you dive in deeper. Good luck @TonyOkoth.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are sending a query to the model let whatever the reason be following is the code :

in your model

```
<?php 
 class SomeModel extends Eloquent
 {
 public static function funcname($filter,$data)
 {
 // the filter passed from controller is in $filter
 }
 }
```

in your controller

```
 $filt = Input::get('name');
 $query = DB::table('wm.top_pages')->where('filter',$filt)->limit(20)->get();

 //pass the data from this controller to funcname function we created in model
 SomeModel::funcname($filt,$query);
```

Comment: I'm not passing anything to my model in my code above. What i would like to do is pass the variable '$filt' to a query in my model as a where-clause.